# Inheritance and lists

Tags: c++, inheritance, sfml

I need to manage ants and colonies for a little game (for experiments in fact).

I have an Element class, which define all the entities in the game (ants, colonies, food, and other stuff…)

All other classes derive from this one.

**My problem :**

I have a class to manage all the entities. The player is able to select what he want. The selected entity is stored : `Element* selection;` If the selected intity is an Ant, the player can move it. But, because the selection variable is an Element pointer, I can't call the `move()` method which is in the Ant class, obviously.

**What I consider to test :**

If I implement a Element method called `isMovable()` which return true or false and maybe if the selection is movable, I will cast it to an Ant ? I don't know what is the right solution.

**My move method:**

```
void Manager::movementEvent(sf::Vector2i mPosition)
{
    sf::Vector2f mousePosition = sf::Vector2f((float)mPosition.x, (float)mPosition.y);
    if(this->selection) {
        // I need to move the selected Ant
    }
}
```

*Thank you for your help !!*

**EDIT**

Here my actual design :

```
class Element {
private:
    sf::Vector2f position;
    int width, height;
public:
    Element();
    Element(sf::Vector2f position, int width, int height);
    Element(const Element & element);
    virtual ~Element();
};

class Colony: public Element {
private:
    int capacity;
    Queen *queen;

public:
    Colony();
    Colony(sf::Vector2f position, int width, int height, int capacity, Queen &queen);
    Colony(Colony const & colony);
    virtual ~Colony();

    Colony& operator=(Colony const& colony);
};

class Ant: public Element
{
private:
    sf::Vector2f destination;
    int number, age, speed;

public:
    Ant();
    Ant(sf::Vector2f position, int number, int age, int width, int height, int speed);
    Ant(const Ant & ant);
    virtual ~Ant();

    Ant& operator=(Ant const& ant);
};

class Manager {
private:
    std::vector<Element*> ants;
    std::vector<Element*> colonies;
    Element* selection;
    std::vector<Ant*> movement;
public:
    Manager();
    virtual ~Manager();

    std::vector<Element*> getAnts();
    std::vector<Element*> getColonies();

    void addAnt(Ant* ant);
    void addColony(Colony* colony);

    void removeAnt(Ant* ant);
    void removeColony(Colony* colony);

    void draw(sf::RenderWindow * window);
    void drawElement(sf::RenderWindow * window, std::vector<Element*> vector);

    void selectionEvent(sf::Vector2i mousePosition);
    bool checkSelection(sf::Vector2f mousePosition, std::vector<Element*> vector);

    void movementEvent(sf::Vector2i mousePosition);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to avoid the design in general, as it strikes me as a forced fit at best.

A base class *should* define behaviors that are common between a number of derived classes and provide a common interface to that common behavior. In this case, however, it seems likely to me that your derived classes *have* practically no common behavior, so you'll have little or nothing in the way of a useful common interface between them.

That being the case, you're likely to lose a great deal more than you gain by forcing them all to derive from a (basically meaningless) "entity" class. In fact, I'd suggest that almost any time you find yourself thinking in terms of a class name as general as "object" or "entity" that doesn't suggest a meaningful set of behaviors, chances are pretty good that you're trying to shove things together that don't really belong together.

All that said, if you *really* insist on doing this anyway, I'd adhere to the basic maxim that it's better to tell than ask. As such, I'd define a `try_to_move` (or possibly just name it `move`) in the base class, but provide a default definition that just fails. Then override that in the Ant class to actually move.

```
class Entity { 
// ...
    virtual bool move_to(Location new_location) { 
        return false;
    }
};

class Ant : public Entity { 
// ...
    virtual bool move_to(Location new_location) { 
        my_location = new_location; 
        return true;
    }
};
```

This way you can tell *anything* derived from `Entity` to move -- but if you tell a `Food` object to move, it'll just fail. This simplifies the calling code considerably. Instead of a pattern like:

```
if (object->can_move()) {
    if (object->move_to(new_location))
        // succeeded
    else
        // failed
}
```

We get code like:

```
if (object->move_to(new_location))
     // succeeded
else
     // failed
```

At least in a typical case, we're likely to end up dealing with the possibility of failure even when we've told an ant to move, so adding the element of asking the object whether it can move before asking it to do so really gains us nothing anyway.

Depending on the situation, you *might* want to change the code a little, so different reasons for failing to move return different error codes, so when/if it fails, you can sort out why. Alternatively, you might prefer to write the code so that it either succeeds at moving, or else throws. Under *these* circumstances (where you rather expect it to fail at least part of the time) that's probably not the best alternative, but it *may* still be worth considering.

I'll reiterate, however, that I think a better design is probably to just keep `Ant`s and `Food` separate, so it's easy to deal with Food as food, and Ants as ants, and not have to sort out at run-time whether something is Food or an Ant to know how you can interact with it.

Comment: you're right, I should rethink my design to keep Ants, Food and other stuff separate. But in case of the selection, I couldn't store it in a variable that's right ? Need to implement a boolean in my classes and loop in the lists to check if entities are selected or not ?

Comment: @kyrillos: Not necessarily. You could, for example, have an "add_if" function that you'd call, passing the type of thing you want to add to the selection, and a pointer to the selection. Each object would then sort out whether to add itself to the selection or not.

Comment: could you provide a example, I think I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

This really smells like you are solving the wrong problem. You will be able to get it to work using flags like `isMovable` and casting, but your code is likely to turn into a mess and give you a headache.

Perhaps your problem is actually

> "I have a class to manage all the entities"

If they are in no way related, they probably should not express an Is-A relationship to Entity. It might be cleaner if you have different containers for each type. How you tie up the actions the user wants with "entities" will be another matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `virtual` method `move()` on your base class, than implement it only for the `Ant` class, so when it's checked the `Element` is movable, it should move:

```
class Element
{
public:
   Element(bool movable) : m_movable(movable) {}

   virtual void move() {};
   bool isMovable() const { return m_movable; }

private:
   bool m_movable;
};

class Ant : public Element
{
public:
   Ant() : Element(true) {}

   void move() { /* move */ }
};

class Food : public Element
{
public:
   Food() : Element(false) {}
};
```

In this way every derived class has a `move()` method, indeed, but it's the inherited from the base class (so it's left blank).

#### EDIT

Occam's razor tells us that in this case you also don't have the need of the `bool m_movable` flag, so the snippet simplifies in:

```
class Element
{
public:
   Element() {}

   virtual void move() {};
};

class Ant : public Element
{
public:
   Ant() {}

   void move() { /* move */ }
};

class Food : public Element
{
public:
   Food() {}
};
```

Comment: you can also remove the `isMovable()` thing and always call `move()` on every derived instance, if it's moveable, the proper method is implemented, if not, it's left blank.

Comment: You don't need the moveable flag then, surely? I just think this way will lead to pain. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: i was just writing that :)